# Insert variables in jQuery checkbox code

Tags: jquery, checkbox

I have the following jquery code:

```
$("#MLSAreaMajor1").prop("checked", false);
$("#MLSAreaMajor2").prop("checked", false);
$("#MLSAreaMajor3").prop("checked", false);
```

I want to loop through this code and replace the MLSAreaMajor with a variable, the 1,2,3 after the MLSAreaMajor would be a variable based on loop number, and the false will also be a variable as it my say false or true.

I can't seem to get the correct syntax and have tried numerous things.

Comment: Is this you want? `$("#" + MLSAreaMajorVariable + LoopVariable).prop("checked", anothervariable)`

Comment: `$("#"+variable+loopvariable).prop("checked", anothervariable);`

Comment: Is that *all* the `MLSAreaMajor` elements, or a subset of them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be something like this

```js
var someVariable = "MLSAreaMajor";
for(var i = 1; i <= someNumber; i++) {
    var condition = false; // check in here if it should be true or false
    $("#"+someVariable+""+i).prop("checked", condition); }
```

Comment: This worked, thanks. Just one comment for other novices like me, I was passing the condition as 'false' instead of false with no quotes, and that caused a problem too.